# Will downloading affected files from Google Drive continue to work after September 13th's security update?

Tags: google-drive-api

We have Google Drive download URLs without resource keys in our database, like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1oj***w9c&export=download
```

Our app's current method of downloading files is to `GET` those URLs, without a resource key:

```
HTTP GET https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1oj***w9c&export=download
```

For files that are affected by the [September 13th security update for Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10729743) (files that appear on the **Impacted files** page in people's Google Drive accounts) will these download URLs continue to work without a resource key?

If the answer is no then alternatively we can parse the `id`'s out of the above URLs and use the [`file.get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) API to download the files (with `?alt=media`), using a service account for authentication. Again, without a resource key. Will *this* method continue to work after September 13th?

If the answer is no then what if anything can we do given that all we have in our DB are `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1oj***w9c&export=download` URLs with no resource keys in them?

Thanks!